# beginner's bash script with parameters to be fed to the commands in the script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I want to make a bash script which invokes some simple commands in the following way

```
./myscript magicword
```

would invoke

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat * | grep "$@"
```

However I want to add one more level of complexity, for example triggering case sensitivity or not. Thus I want to include he parsing of arguments such as

```
 ./myscript --case-insensitive magicword
```

which should be interpreted by the script as `grep -i "$@"`.

I have seen many tutorials about bash scripting with arguments, and `case` structures, but those had to do mostly with each executing different commands altogether, or assigning variables (which are not actually using them as command options).

I didn't find a way of a syntax such as `grep $1 "$@"` or something, where $1 ought to be null, or anything else.

Comment: Read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (and [this](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)). In the end you'll probably want to use [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) or similar. Or just run `grep ... *` instead of having the script in the  first place.

Comment: Why are you `cat`ing you can pass files to grep `grep "$@" *`

Comment: Thanks for the links. 
My actual question is about how to feed command-line arguments as internal arguments in the comands inside the shell. The cat and grep example is for the sake of simplicity (my intended script does different things and is slightly more complex) so I am not interested in the usage of these specific commands. :D

Comment: You might not want to use `getopt(1)`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 for details about that (bottom section) and the top section for a simple manual option loop.

Comment: @JID `grep "$@" *` actually behaves differently than `cat * | grep "$@"`. The former will cause grep to list the names of files in which matches are found. Some implementations have workarounds like `-h`, but POSIX `grep` does not appear to. Thus, `cat * | grep "$@"` appears to be the only portable way to search multiple files without listing their names.